# Unable to convert Task<bool> to bool in Xamarin forms CrossConnectivity Plugin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In My App.xaml.cs file I am checking Host Connectivity using CrossConnectivity plugin.
Here is my code

```cs
CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += async (sender, args) =>
{
    if (!args.IsConnected)
        DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().ShowSnackBar("No Internet Connection");
    if (args.IsConnected)
    {
        Task<bool> response = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable("http://ws.****abc.com/", 5000);
        bool res = await response;
        if (!res)
        {
            await Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Message", "Service not available,Please contact to your system admin", "Ok");
        }
    }
};
```

By Host connection is fine, but I am getting false response.
How to solve this?

Comment: Instead of `if (!response)` wouldn't it be `if (!res)` ?

Comment: it was little misspell,actually it will be if(!res),but it doesn't work as espected.It always returns false.

Comment: So basically your problem is that `IsRemoteReachable` method is returning false, nothing to do with converting `Task<bool>` to `bool` or anything related to the code you posted

Comment: Is the url reachable? If running on iOS calls from your app to http (as opposed to https) sites will be blocked by default unless you set some keys in the info.plist to allow non secure settings. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats

Comment: I am running this app only android device,and the url is reachable perfetcly.But IsRemoteReachable methos task<bool> returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the port to `IsRemoteReachable` method. So the code is like this

```
CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable("http://ws.****abc.com/", 80, 5000);
```

And the more detail code is:

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
            if (DoIHaveInternet())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Great!!!!!!");
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("No!!!!!!");
            }



            CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (!args.IsConnected)
                    Console.WriteLine("not connected!!!!!!!!");
                    //DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().ShowSnackBar("No Internet Connection");
                if (args.IsConnected)
                {
                    Task<bool> response = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable("https://m.baidu.com/", 80, 5000);
                    bool res = await response;
                    if (!res)
                    {
                        await Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Message", "Service not available,Please contact to your system admin", "Ok");
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

I debug this code using Google Pixel phone, and the capture shows the response returns true:
[image]

Note:

1 Make sure you setup CrossConnectivity plugin correctly referring to [this](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/GettingStarted.html)

2 Add ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permissions for android

3 Make sure the url is useful by your testing device. You can check it by opening it in your chrome on your device or simulator first.

Comment: so how to get the response in a boolean variable?

Comment: I edited the answer and you can use the code to get the response in a boolean variable, just as you wrote.

Comment: actually my url is working fine but its always return false,but I am not providing the port number inside IsRemoteReachable().

Comment: I suggest you add the port number, 80, for example. Actually, I also got the false value when I did not add port number; but when I added port number 80, it returns true.

Comment: Great! If it helped, I would be appreciated if you can mark my answer.